# How to make a non-linear problem linear?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following constraint which is the product of multiple binary variables:
$1- \prod_i^n (1-(c_i x_i)) >= T$

where $x_i$ is a binary variable, $c_i$ is a constant and $T$ is a constant too. Are there any way to make this problem linear?

Comment: in general i think the answer would be no. where does that problem come from?

Comment: Don't know a whole lot about linear programming, but couldn't you redefine the variables and $T$ and take a logarithm to turn it into a sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If $x_i = 1$ multiply by $1-c_i$, otherwise multiply by $1$." $$\prod_i(1-c_ix_i) = \prod_i (1-c_i)^{x_i}$$

So $$\begin{align}1-\prod_i(1-c_ix_i) \geq T \Leftrightarrow 1-T &\geq \prod_i(1-c_ix_i) \\
&= \prod_i (1-c_i)^{x_i}
\end{align}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow\log(1-T) \geq \sum_i x_i \log(1-c_i)$$

So the constraint becomes

$$T' \geq \sum_i x_i c_i'$$
where $T' = \log(1-T)$, $c_i' = \log(1-c_i)$.

Answer (score 1):

From
$1- \prod_i^n (1-(c_i x_i)) >= T$
we get
$\prod_i^n (1-(c_i x_i)) \le 1-T$.

Taking logs,
$\sum_i^n \log(1-(c_i x_i)) \le \log(1-T)$.

If this isn't good enough,
you can approximate with
$-\ln(1-x)
=x+x^2/2+...
> x
$,
so
$\ln(1-x) < -x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer